# Add a row to a table using Angular 8

Tags: angular

I want to add dynamic rows to a table. When i using below code, row is added. but that row is duplicated.

new-betting.component.html

```
<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01code" [formControl]="betOption2">
    <option selected>Game Code</option>
    <option [value]="option2.id" *ngFor="let option2 of options2$ | async">{{ option2.value }}</option>
</select>

<select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01dscr" [formControl]="betOption">
     <option selected>Description</option>
     <option [value]="option.id" *ngFor="let option of options$ | async">{{ option.value }}</option>
</select>

     <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm btn-round waves-effect waves-light m-1" id="addnewrecord" (click)="addRow()">Add Bet</button>

<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async">
     <td>{{ row.value }}</td>
     <td>{{ row.value }}</td>
     <td>Rs.1500</td>
</tr>
```

new-betting.component.ts

```
export class NewBettingComponent implements OnInit {
betOption = new FormControl();
betOption2 = new FormControl();
options$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ id: 1, value: 'Mark Verndom' }, { id: 2, value: 'Jacob Brown' }, { id: 3, value: 'Steve Rogurs' }]);
options2$ = new BehaviorSubject([{ id: 1, value: 'CSN1' }, { id: 2, value: 'CIA5' }, { id: 3, value: 'CSI7' }]);

selectedOptions$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);
constructor() { }

ngOnInit(){
}

addRow() {
if (!this.betOption.value) {
    return;
}
if (!this.betOption2.value) {
  return;
}
const yourSelectedObject = this.options$.value.find(el => el.id === Number(this.betOption.value));
const yourSelectedObject2 = this.options2$.value.find(el2 => el2.id === Number(this.betOption2.value));
this.selectedOptions$.next([...this.selectedOptions$.value, ...[yourSelectedObject],...[yourSelectedObject2]]);

}
}
```

I have added my output screenshot with this problem. Once I click `Add bet` button two selected options are added in separate rows as show in screen shot. I want to get them in one row.

[image]

The output should be like this :

[image]

Comment: Why do you emit `this.selectedOptions$.value` each time? You want to have some history of selections?

Comment: For me it seems you add two rows at the end of the list. You should create a new object from selectedoption and selectedoption2 before add at the end of the list

Comment: @tano I started Angular four days ago. So i don't have much knowledge about angular. Can you do this as a answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sjf57g) of your code, so it's easier to understand what's going on. Let's examine your code.
After the first successful `addRow` Function call your `this.selectedOptions$ | async` will resolve into a next array:

```
0: Object
   id: 2
   value: "Jacob Brown"
1: Object
   id: 1
   value: "CSN1"
```

What's going next? You are iterating over this array so the first row of the table is the first object and you are just writing `value` property of this object two times. The next row is the second object and you're writing it's value two times. That's why you get the situation you're asking about.

In order to fix it you should rewrite your code a bit, for example:

```
// Emmiting new value
this.selectedOptions$.next([
    ...this.selectedOptions$.value, 
    {desc: yourSelectedObject, code: yourSelectedObject2}
]);

// Rendering
<tr *ngFor="let row of selectedOptions$ | async">
     <td>{{ row.desc.value }}</td>
     <td>{{ row.code.value }}</td>
     <td>Rs.1500</td>
</tr>
```

Here is an updated [StackBlitz version](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9cc7kz?file=src/app/app.component.ts) which works as you expected.